# Android Jetpack Compose Project vs "Regular" Jetpack Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Is it impossible to use any of the other Android Studio project templates ie. Bottom Navigation, Google Maps Activity, etc. along with Jetpack Compose? I tried adding the Compose dependencies and import libraries into the other projects without using  New Empty Compose Activity" template but it doesn't work on the Gradle nor importing Compose type calls.

> Could not get unknown property 'compose_version' for object of type
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ComposeOptionsImpl
>
> e: This version (1.0.0-beta07) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin
> version 1.4.32 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.10 which
> is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or
> `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn
> you!).

Comment: As described in the error you are using kotlin 1.5.0 and compose-1.0.0-beta07 doesn't work with kotlin 1.5

Comment: Update: 
- compose '1.0.0-beta09' is now out which supports Kotlin 1.5.
- Creating a Compose project via Android Studio simply automatically generates the proper dependencies in the gradle files. You can create a empty project etc and manually add Compose to the project following Google's instructions: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#configure_gradle

Answer (score 1):

Use latest version of Kotlin plugin and refer to this android Developer's document https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#create-new

Comment: The latest version of the kotlin plugin available is 1.5.0 but jetpack compose beta07 won't work with that it still uses 1.4.32